# organize nested mysql databse structure for Multilevel marketing system

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-structures, nested

If someone already done nested database structure for Multilevel Marketing (MLM) system, please share your knowledge, because i am in stuck.

I have two options: first one is old way, table structure like 
id,
name,
parent_id etc,

second options is Hierarchical Data structure in MySql something like,
id, 
name,
lft,
rgt, etc,

Well, the main thing is both has pros and cons, please advice me.

Lastly, about the tree structure should be like this

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Multi-level_marketing_tree_diagram.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database design would appear to fall into a classic SQL anti-pattern known as ***Naive Trees***. I strongly recommend you review http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/sql-antipatterns-strike-back - epsecially the section beginning around slide 48.

Comment: Thank you GoogleGuy. I have found my way that how to make design for my application.